# How to get source (sender) for an event in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function

```
@IBAction func fblogin(sender: AnyObject) {
println (sender)
}
```

The action of two button is this function. If I print sender nil gets printer. How do I check which button called it. Do I need to create outlet for buttons or how do I create ids for buttons?

Comment: If you know that its only UIButtons calling that function then you can make sender a UIButton isntead of AnyObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sender`'s `tag` value

Just connect both buttons to your action, and check with:

```c
    if(sender.tag == 1) {
    ... button 1
    } else if( sender.tag == 2) {
    .. button 2
    }
```

And use sender from type UIButton (you can select it directly in Xcode too)

- how set `tag` value？

  - code

    - `someBtn.tag = 1;`

      - normally inside `ViewDidLoad`
  - UI

    - XCode->Storyboard->select UI (your UIButton) -> right side panel(Inspector) -> Attribute Inspector -> View -> Tag

      - [image]

Comment: How to set tag for a button?

Comment: You can set it in Xcode, or create an Outlet for your buttons, and use (for example) "button.tag = 1" and "button2.tag = 2" in ViewDidLoad

Comment: may be you should cast the sender as the Button type